# Xamarin Forms How to get the name of the wi-fi network in which the device is connected

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, device-orientation

Does anyone know how one can have the name of the wi-fi network in which the device is currently connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-display?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android)

```
var orientation = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Orientation;

if (orientation == Orientation.Landscape) 
{
  MainPage = new Page1();
} else {
  MainPage = new Page2();
}
```

Comment: DisplayOrientation.Landscape

Comment: Exist an Event than could change the 2 pages on App.cs?

Answer (score 0):

the solution to my problem, for now, I solved it this way:

in the App.cs :

public App ()
        {

```
            MainPage =new NavigationPage( new HomePage());

    }
```

in the HomePage.xaml.cs :

protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
        {

```
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

        if(width > height)
        {
            _ = GoToPageAsync();
        }
    }

    private  async Task GoToPageAsync()
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new TestPage());
    }
```

in the TestPage.xaml.cs :

protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
        {

```
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

        if (width < height)
        {
            _ = GoToPageAsync();
        }
    }

    private async Task GoToPageAsync()
    {
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
```

If anyone has any better ideas ...